# latexdiff with align environment

Tags: latexdiff

I have a file `old.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\nn}{\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x^2\nn
x^3
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

and a file `new.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\nn}{\\}

\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

If I run `latexdiff --exclude-safecmd="nn" old.tex new.tex > diff.tex` , I get `diff.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
%DIF LATEXDIFF DIFFERENCE FILE
%DIF DEL old.tex   Wed Dec  8 13:48:59 2021
%DIF ADD new.tex   Wed Dec  8 13:34:53 2021
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\nn}{\\}
%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFmodbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFmodend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF LISTINGS PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{listings} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstdefinelanguage{DIFcode}{ %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF DIFCODE_UNDERLINE %DIF PREAMBLE
  moredelim=[il][\color{red}\sout]{\%DIF\ <\ }, %DIF PREAMBLE
  moredelim=[il][\color{blue}\uwave]{\%DIF\ >\ } %DIF PREAMBLE
} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstdefinestyle{DIFverbatimstyle}{ %DIF PREAMBLE
    language=DIFcode, %DIF PREAMBLE
    basicstyle=\ttfamily, %DIF PREAMBLE
    columns=fullflexible, %DIF PREAMBLE
    keepspaces=true %DIF PREAMBLE
} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstnewenvironment{DIFverbatim}{\lstset{style=DIFverbatimstyle}}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstnewenvironment{DIFverbatim*}{\lstset{style=DIFverbatimstyle,showspaces=true}}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}

\DIFdelbegin \begin{align*}
\DIFdel{x^2\nn
x^3
}\end{align*}%DIFAUXCMD
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{text
}\DIFaddend 

\end{document}
```

which does not compile. I thought that the `--exclude-safecmd` flag would tell `latexdiff` give me output that looks like

```
....
\DIFdel{x^2}\nn
\DIFdel{x^3
}
....
```

so that the `\nn` command is not inside `\DIFdel{}`. Can I run the command differently to get output that compiles?

Comment: a tool like latexdiff  can not know your local `\nn` command has special syntax requirements in an align. What is the reason for defining a local name `\nn` that is  longer than the standard `\\ ` ?

Comment: That's a fair point. The actual definition is ```\nonumber\\```. But I wanted to make sure my working example was minimal. I thought that the ```--exclude-safecmd="nn"``` flag was supposed to make sure that command didn't get put inside a ```\DIFdel{}```

Comment: Oh actually I'd missed that commandline, OK perhaps, but align is a very delcate thing and it's not surprising that this gets hard. `\nn` really doesn't save a lot over `\notag\\ `  That said you can probably define `\nn` so it works in `\Difdel` I'll have a look...

Comment: I guess I could have made my question more clear. I had thought that ```--exclude-safecmd``` was supposed to tell ```latexdiff``` to not put things in ```\DIFdel```. Is that not so?

Comment: yes I think it is (although I don't know latexdiff that well) but it's a tricky area and hiding `\\ ` makes it trickier so I'm not that surprised it fails